# jQuery Datepicker - Tab Index Order is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tab Index Order is not working in IE. We have datetime field control. On focus it shows jQuery calendar. As we tab to move next element, it still focusing on that same field. Hence tab index ordering is not working properly in IE only. 
Please Help.

Comment: Please post what you tried !.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Welcome to SO!  For best results please enclude your code showing your efforts, and as specific as you can what the problem is.

Comment: This is my Code: function pageLoad(sender, args) {

    $("input[id*='Date']").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function (input, obj) {
            $(input).after($(input).datepicker('widget'));
        },

    });
    $("input[id*='Date']").on('change', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
        }, 400);

    });
}

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
onkeydown="return false;"
```

Property from the input `datepicker` field.